# The range of $f(P)=4XP(0)+2P+P'$

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I find the range of $f:\mathbb R_2[X] \to \mathbb R_2[X]$ defined by $f(P)=4XP(0)+2P+P'$ ?

My idea is to set $P(X)=aX^2+bX+c$ and thus,

$$f(P)=4Xc+2(aX^2+bX+c)+2aX+b=a(2X+2X^2)+b(2X+1)+c(4X+2).$$

Can I conclude that $\operatorname{Im}(f)=\operatorname{span}(2X+2X^2, 2X+1, 4X+2)$?

I did it by instinct, and if it works, I don't know why. Any explantation is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it works. Let $S = \operatorname{span}\{2X + 2X^2, 2X + 1, 4X + 2\}$.

Your calculation shows that for $P \in \mathbb{R}_2[X]$, $f(P) \in S$, so $\operatorname{Im}(f) \subseteq S$.

For the opposite inclusion, if $Q \in S$, then there are $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$Q = \alpha(2X+2X^2) + \beta(2X + 1) + \gamma(4X+2).$$

From your calculation we see that $f(\alpha X^2 + \beta X + \gamma) = Q$, so $Q \in \operatorname{Im}(f)$ and hence $S \subseteq \operatorname{Im}(f)$.

Therefore, $\operatorname{Im}(f) = S$.

As menag points out, $S$ is also equal to $\operatorname{span}\{2X + 2X^2, 2X + 1\}$. Your answer is still correct (the span is still $S$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just by curiosity, this is isomorphic to $span(1,X)$, $span(1,X^2)$ and $span(X,X^2)$ right ? If yes, why do we do that complicate and say it's $span(2X+2X^2, 2X+1)$ ? Sorry for the question, and thank you for your answer and your futur answer, it's really nice from you. Good evening.

Comment: Yes, they are isomorphic to $S$ as they are all two-dimensional, but they are not equal to $S$. To answer questions such as "Is $X^2 + X$ in the range of $f$?" we need to know $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ precisely, not just up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

I assume with $\mathbb{R}_2[X]$ you denote the degree $2$ polynomials with real coefficients.

Observe that $f(P + Q) = f(P) + f(Q)$ and $f(\lambda P) = \lambda f(P)$. Thus $f$ is a linear map. Since the elements $X^2, X, 1$ are a basis of $\mathbb{R}_2[X]$, their images $f(X^2) = 2X^2 + 2X, f(X) = 2X + 1, f(1) = 4X + 2$ generate the image of $f$. Now we have $4X + 2 = 2 \cdot (2X + 1)$, and therefore
$$\operatorname{Im}(f) = \operatorname{span}(X^2 + X, 2X+1),$$
where the remaining two polynomials are obviously linear independent.

Comment: While this accurately answers the question of determining the range of $f$, I don't think it addresses the OP's concern, namely why we can conclude the image is what it is. In particular, I think understanding why what the OP has done is correct is effectively equivalent to understanding why the images $X^2$, $X$ and $1$ generate the image of $f$.